# Correct usage of RxSwift with TableView

Tags: mvvm, swift3, tableview, rx-swift

I don't know how transfer the data between ModelView and ViewController. In

SelectModelViewController

```
class SelectModelViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

var markViewModel : MarkViewModel?
let markService = MarkService()
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    markViewModel = MarkViewModel(markService: markService)
    markViewModel?.data.asObservable()
        .bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (_, element, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = element
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
}
```

MarkViewModel has an error. I'am doing something wrong

struct MarkViewModel {

```
let markService: MarkService
var data: Driver<[Mark]>

init(markService: MarkService) {
    self.markService = markService

    data = markService.get()
        .map { result in
            switch result {
            case.success(let marks):
                return marks.map { mark in
                    return mark
                }
            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
            }

        }.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: .error(.other))
}}
```

MarkService

struct MarkService {

```
func get() -> Observable<Result<[Mark]>> {
    return URLSession.shared.rx.json(url: URL(string: API.BaseURL)!)
        .retry(3)
        .map {
            var marks = [Mark]()
            guard let json = $0 as? [String: Any],
                let items = json["RBMarks"] as? [[String : Any]] else {
                    return .error(.badJSON)
            }
            for item in items {
                if let mark = Mark(json: item) {
                    marks.append(mark)
                } else {
                    return .error(.badJSON)
                }
            }
            return .success(marks)
        }
        .catchErrorJustReturn(.error(.noInternet))
}}
```

Comment: You should try and provide some detail as to why this isn't working. What's going wrong and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @StefanDorunga I just do not understand  how transfer the data between ModelView and ViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can return `Observable<Result<[Mark]>>` from `MarkService` instead of `Any`. This will be useful later on to display them.

```
struct MarkService {

    func get() -> Observable<Result<[Mark]>> {
        return URLSession.shared.rx.json(url: URL(string: API.BaseURL)!)
            .retry(3)
            .map {
                var marks = [Mark]()
                guard let json = $0 as? [String: Any],
                    let items = json["RBMarks"] as? [[String : Any]] else {
                        return .error(.badJSON)
                }
                for item in items {
                    if let mark = Mark(json: item) {
                        marks.append(mark)
                    } else {
                        return .error(.badJSON)
                    }
                }
                return .success(marks)
            }
            .catchErrorJustReturn(.error(.noInternet))
    }
}
```

Then, let's remove the subscription to `data` in `MarkViewModel`. We'll also transform the marks to something that is more suited for presentation.

```
struct MarkViewModel {

    let markService: MarkService
    var data: Driver<[String]>
    var marks: Variable<[Mark]>
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    init(markService: MarkService) {
        self.markService = markService


        data = markService.get()
            .map { result in
                guard case .success(let marks) = result else {
                    return ["Error while getting marks"]
                }

                return marks.map { mark in
                    "For assignment \(mark.assignmentName), you were marked with \(mark.grade)/10"
                }
            }
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: .error(.other))
    }
}
```

Now, in view controller, we can use RxSwift's table view bindings to display those data

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

func viewDidLoad() {
    viewModel.data
        .bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: UITableViewCell.self)) { (_, element, cell) in
            cell.textLabel?.text = element
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

This is obviously only an example of how you could do it and code will change depending on the requirements for specific views.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I was returning generic enum `Result<Any>` from `MarkService` for handler errors. How that code will be look if `MarkService `will return `Result<Any>`

Comment: The strength of `Result` is actually that I can hold a type or an error. So no need to use `Any` here. But if you really need to, you'll want to change the `guard` in view controller to `guard case .success(let anyMarks) = result, let marks = anyMarks as? [Mark] else {`

Comment: I edited the question, i have an error in viewModel `Cannot assign value of type 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, _>' to type 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, [Mark]>' (aka 'SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, Array<Mark>>')'`

Comment: In view model, replace `case .error(let error): print(error)` with `case .error(let error): throw error`.

Comment: In the bindTo() method (now drive() method), does anyone know when the call to setup the cell is made? Is it when all the data is received, thus initializing all cells of the list, or is it only called right before a cell is displayed, thus lazy loading the cells of the list as the user scrolls down?